# Carrierwave Cloudfront URL With params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

So I've tried everything, and I cannot for the life of me pass `response-content-disposition` or any other params through the URL when I use `CloudFront`.

This works fine with regular `S3`, `Carrierwave`, and `Fog`... just not Cloudfront:

`Book.first.filename_url(:query => {"response-content-disposition" => "attachment"})`

Returns just the cloudfront URL by itself, with no query params.

I have public set to `true`, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With public files, I think you should be able to simply get the url back that it offers and append your own query params. Not particularly elegant, but workable. Assuming that works (which I'm not certain of) we could then work to patch things appropriately to make this more directly supported.